# Rails + Devise: How to restrict a user from editing records that do not belong to him

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Rails, Devise and Mongoid.

A user can only have one project (`has_one :profile`) but all users (and non authenticated users) can see a list of projects (I have this working). When a user is logged in they see "edit and delete" buttons next to the projects (via wrapping those buttons in `<% if user_signed_in? %>`). However, a signed in user sees these buttons next to all project and can edit or delete them all.

How do I restrict a logged on user to only be able to edit only his project?

As a bonus, is it possible to show specific content or html around the project that belongs to the signed in user (such as text that says "this is your project" or an additional class around the project's html)?

Comment: The conditional you describe can do it, but you might check out https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/ for a more robust solution

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should use can can for that or not, I guess I should.

Comment: You can add another condition <% if user_signed_in? and project.user == current_user %> but CanCan is a much better and safer solution, you want permissions to be done on the controller/model level, not views.

Answer (score 6):

CanCan is great when you have multiple users being able to modify the same resource, and you need to keep track of who has which permissions. But if it's strictly the case that only the user who owns the project can modify it, CanCan is probably overkill.

Hide the links in the view as suggested by iouri, and then in your controller do something like:

```
def edit
  if current_user != @project.user
    # Redirect them to an error page
  else
    # Render the view
  end
end
```

Better yet, create a method like:

```
def user_owns_project?
  @project.user == current_user
end
```

Then set up a before filter for edit, update and destroy to redirect to the error page if the user doesn't own the project.

**EDIT**: Your before filter will also ned to find the project and set `@project`. CanCan takes care of this for you too with `load_and_authorize_resource`, but I'd still avoid using it unless you need, or expect to need, fine-grained permissions control.

Comment: how you associate the user to the project, in order to be able to use the following expression: `project.user == current_user` ?

Answer (score 2):

Devise is to control "authentication", this should not to be your responsibility.

You want to control "authorizations", for that [CanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) is better.